# How should we treat answers on off-topic questions?

Tags: discussion

Right now, we have this very off-topic [question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33244/what-are-the-good-websites-for-hotel-reviews-for-india). I already voted to close, but there are not enough votes yet, so it stays open for now.

In my review queue, there was an answer on this question as a first post. Now, I'm not sure what to do with this answer (and others on off-topic questions that are still open).

On the one hand, the answer itself is acceptable, since it answers the question. But on the other hand, the answer is off-topic too, because the question itself is.

I marked the answer as "looks good", but I just want to delete the whole thing.

What is the right way of treating these kinds of answers?

Answer (score 2):

Unless they're actively harmful in their own right (offensive, spam) just ignore them and focus on the question.

When you encounter such an answer in /review, you'll want to break out to the full question and close / flag / downvote that - what you do for the answer in review is mostly irrelevant, since it'll likely be deleted soon anyway... If it's pretty bad even in the context of the question you might still want to down-vote it of course.